# GA4 Ecommerce tracking 2 issues: purchases with no transaction ID's + can I include payment_type n my purcase event paarmeters

Tags: google-analytics-4, enhanced-ecommerce

[image]I am looking into a GA4 ecommerce set up that isnt reporting 100% accurately.(using tag manager)
I set up a report (exploration/Freeform) with Transaction id's as rows and purchases and purchase revenue as values as part of my investigation.

I am seeing purchases with no transaction ID's, I am also seeing some transaction ID's with multiple purchases (I understood there should always be only 1 pre trasaction ID)

Trying get more information by getting some custom parameters included, I see that the Event add_payment has the parameter payment_type -> thuinking of adding it into the purchase event but cant find any info wether its supported or how could I check if its included in the data layer values during the purhcase event in the first place.( wil would love a tutorial on how to check the data layer vlues using dev tools, found a few but didnt manage to view the details like the tutorial suggested, the site is a single page web app).

Can anyone offer any advice? (see link for sample of what I am seeing in my report)
Thanks in advance

Sam

[Purchases by transaction ID showing purchases with NO transaction ID and others with multiple purchases for 1 transaction ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOOhf.png)

EDIT: I added an additional image, shows how the funnel steps are populated with actions but all transaction IDs & revenue have none, the site is a single page application and this is making me think that events are firing mulriple times (looks like twice) but that previous steps arent connected to the events taht are recorded as transactions

Comment: I'd check if the page processing the purchase event can trigger it multiple times if the page is refreshed. And if it sends invalid transactions if visited without a purchase. I believe it's fine to send payment_type in purchase events.

Comment: Thanks Tony! I see 2 purchase events fire at each time. Now about my payment_type. For users the value is by default "Pay online" I only see the payment_info event fire if user changes it  to "cash on pick up" at which point it gets a value, also this happens before the purchase event, so my follow up is: 1 -  does it make sense to try and set a default value "online payment" using tag manager (or should I ask my developer to set it in the data layer) to account for when user does not touch it; and 2 - does the data layer valye persist over to the purchase event which happens later?

Comment: And sadly, even though I am not able yet to identify the scenario when this happens, the cash register system is recording more sales taking place than my analytics,...

Comment: It sounds like you need to find where the second payment event comes from. Chromes network tab has an Initiator column (you may need to add it) that shows you the stack trace when you hover over it.

I'd send the payment_info event once you know they have passed the step indicating how they are going to pay. It would help when doing a funnel report for your checkout.

I'm not familiar with using the dataLayer. I guess the developer could work it out.

You will always miss some purchases with third-party analytics software due to things like add blockers or consent requirements.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I will look into it. Reached out to the developer side as I see the datalayer needs work in anycase.